# Ninject and windows phone 8.1

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8.1, ninject

I have some issues right now with my Windows Phone 8.1 app while trying to add Ninject to it.

I have a System.IO.FileNotFoundException when I instanciate a new StandardKernel (seems that the exception occurs in Ninject.dll). Here is the entire message of the exception :

> Exception = {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0...

I tried with several versions of Ninject:

1. v2.0.1: found in NuGet (this is the highest version I was able to install, when trying to install v3.2.0 from NuGet the installation fails)
2. v3.2.0: found on ninject.org. I took the .NET 4 version.

Both gave me the same result with the exception showed above.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Thomas

Comment: have you tried [Portable.Ninject](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.Ninject/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the WinRT fork available at https://github.com/remogloor/ninject, because there is no official Ninject for WinRT as far as I know.

If you are looking for a all-in-one solution, the Caliburn Micro MVVM framework also contains a simple IoC container, which is easy to use.

Unity is also available for Winrt.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that Visual Studio Express 2013 is not really friendly with this WinRT version though. I'm downloading VS 2010 to see if it's working (right now VS is expecting me to transform these projects in win8.1 projects, don't really know why...). I'll look at your other ideas if this is not working. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Well can't find any solution to make Visual Studio able to open the WinRT Ninject project. Caliburn Micro it will be then.
Thanks again for your answer.